# Replacing a value in a cell with another

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am writing a macro in Excel spreadsheets to replace a value in one cell by the content of another cell and loop through the original text replacing the same value, whenever it sees this word.
For example, I have a text in a range of cells, where every line has a word "tagname" I want to replace "tagname" with the value of cell A1 of the same spreadsheet, for example to say "Maggie" instead of tagname.
This is my code thus far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim OriginalText As Range
Dim CorrectedText As Range
'definition of ranges

Set OriginalText = Range("H4:H10")

'setting of ranges

For Each OriginalText In CorrectedText

CorrectedText.Value = Replace(OriginalText.Value, "tagname", Range("D2").Value)

Next OriginalText
'a loop through the original text to replace the word "tagname" with the value of cell D4

Columns(2).Clear 'clear column 2 for the Corrected Text
Range("A24:A30").Offset(, 1).Value = CorrectedText
'copy corrected text in these cells
End Sub
```

I get runtime error 424, object required.

Comment: The last line should be `Range("A24:A30").Offset(, 1).Value = CorrectedText.Value`

Comment: That being said you do not need to loop,  It appears that you are replacing in place.  Instead of the whole loop just place this: `correctedText.Replace What:="tagname", Replacement:=Range("D2")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put all of it together, this is how I would do it.

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim correctedText As Range
Dim OriginalText As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim cel As Range

Set correctedText = Range("B24")
Set OriginalText = Range("H4:H10")

OriginalText.Replace "tagname", Range("d4")
correctedText.Resize(OriginalText.Rows.Count).Value = OriginalText.Value
OriginalText.Replace Range("d4"), "tagname"

End Sub
```

Or if you really want the loop:

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim correctedText As Range
Dim OriginalText As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim cel As Range

Set correctedText = Range("B24")
Set OriginalText = Range("H4:H10")
i = 0
For Each cel In OriginalText
    correctedText.Offset(i).Value = Replace(cel.Value, "tagname", Range("d4"))
    i = i + 1
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: I am now looking to loop through the ranges D4 to D10 executing the same loop over and over. I tried putting 2 loops, one within the other, but all I get is the same text three times over. Could you kindly loop at my code to see where I went wrong?

Comment: Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim correctedText As Range
Dim OriginalText As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim cel1 As Range
Dim cel2 As Range

Set correctedText = Range("B24")
Set OriginalText = Range("H3:H20")
Set loopText = Range("D2:D4")
i = 0
j = 0
For Each cel2 In loopText

    For Each cel1 In OriginalText
        correctedText.Offset(i).Value = Replace(cel1.Value, "tagname", Range("D2"))
        i = i + 1
    Next cel1
j = j + 1
Next cel2
End Sub

Comment: @K.Nadkina A couple of things: 1) if my answer was correct for what was asked, then you should mark it such, by hitting the green check found under the down arrow. 2) This is a second question with a new problem and should be asked on its own. It is considered bad form to ask a second question inside the first. **That being said; Change the `Range("D2")` at the end of the replace statement to `cel2.value`**.

Comment: @K.Nadkina Just so you know the counter j is not doing anything and is not needed.

Comment: thank you, @Scott - still issues. I have posted a new question here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742474/looping-through-values-in-excel-cells-to-replace-in-the-text>