# Looping through values in cells to replace in the text

Tags: vba, excel

This is a next question after [Looping through Excel Values in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699753/replacing-a-value-in-a-cell-with-another/33700469?noredirect=1#comment55252949_33700469).

The original text's "tagname" word is being replaced by that in cell D2 in all instances. However, it has to continue to be replaced by the range of cells which I defined under loopText (D2 to D4).
I have created two loops, one within the other.
Please, help me as it gives me the following:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Below is my code:

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim correctedText As Range
Dim OriginalText As Range
Dim loopText As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim cel As Range
Dim cel2 As Range

Set correctedText = Range("B24")
Set OriginalText = Range("H3:H20")
Set loopText = Range("D2:D4")
i = 0
For Each cel2 In loopText

    For Each cel In OriginalText
        correctedText.Offset(i).Value = Replace(cel.Value, "tagname", Range(cel2.Value))
            i = i + 1
    Next cel

Next cel2
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(cel2.Value)` needs to be just `cel2.Value`.  `cel2` is a range already.

Comment: @scott-craner thank you, works:)!