# Do Until IsEmpty to loop through the user-defined ranges

Tags: vba, excel

This is a continuation of the discussion [Looping through values in cells to replace in the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742474/looping-through-values-in-cells-to-replace-in-the-text)

The following code take the value in cell D2 and populates its value in the OriginalText in all instances where the word "tagname" is used.
Then it loops through the loopText range and produces the correctedText range.
I am looking to use Do UntilEmpty command loop so that the loopText range depends on the user range input, say if the user populates cells D2:D54 then all of then are executed.

Below is my code, but I keep getting a run-time error '91'

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Please, help.
Thanks.

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim correctedText As Range
Dim OriginalText As Range
Dim loopText As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim cel As Range
Dim cel2 As Range

Do Until IsEmpty(loopText.Value)

Set correctedText = Range("B10")
Set OriginalText = Range("H3:H20")
Set loopText = Range("D2")
i = 0
Columns(2).Clear
For Each cel2 In loopText

    For Each cel In OriginalText
        correctedText.Offset(i).Value = Replace(cel.Value, "tagname", cel2.Value)
        i = i + 1
    Next cel

Next cel2

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You only need the two loops,  The first loop was changed to do what you are looking for.

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim correctedText As Range
Dim OriginalText As Range
Dim loopText As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim cel As Range
Dim cel2 As Range
Dim j As Long

Set correctedText = Range("B10")
Set OriginalText = Range("H3:H20")
Set loopText = Range("D2")
i = 0
j = 0
Columns(2).Clear

Do Until IsEmpty(loopText.Offset(j).Value)

    For Each cel In OriginalText
        correctedText.Offset(i).Value = Replace(cel.Value, "tagname", loopText.Offset(j).Value)
        i = i + 1
    Next cel
    j = j + 1
Loop

End Sub
```